# Understanding and Implementing a Force based graph layout algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, layout, graph-algorithm

I'm trying to implement a force base graph layout algorithm, based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-based_algorithms_(graph_drawing)

My first attempt didn't work so I looked at

http://blog.ivank.net/force-based-graph-drawing-in-javascript.html

and

https://github.com/dhotson/springy

I changed my implementation based on what I thought I understood from those two but I haven't managed to get it right and I'm hoping someone can help? JavaScript isn't my strong point so be gentle... If you're wondering why write my own. In reality I have no real reason to write my own I'm just trying to understand how the algorithm is implemented. Especially in my first link, that demo is brilliant.

This is what I've come up with

```
    //support function.bind - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
    Function.prototype.bind = function (oThis) {
        if (typeof this !== "function") {
            // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5 internal IsCallable function
            throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable");
        }
        var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
        fToBind = this,
        fNOP = function () {},
        fBound = function () {
            return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP
                ? this
                : oThis || window,
                aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };
        fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
        fBound.prototype = new fNOP();
        return fBound;
    };
}
(function() {
    var lastTime = 0;
    var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
    for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
        window.cancelAnimationFrame =
        window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
    }
    if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
        window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
            var currTime = new Date().getTime();
            var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
            var id = window.setTimeout(function() {
                callback(currTime + timeToCall);
            },
            timeToCall);
            lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
            return id;
        };
    if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
            clearTimeout(id);
        };
}());
function Graph(o){
    this.options=o;
    this.vertices={};
    this.edges={};//form {vertexID:{edgeID:edge}}
}
/**
 *Adds an edge to the graph. If the verticies in this edge are not already in the
 *graph then they are added
 */
Graph.prototype.addEdge=function(e){
    //if vertex1 and vertex2 doesn't exist in this.vertices add them
    if(typeof(this.vertices[e.vertex1])==='undefined')
        this.vertices[e.vertex1]=new Vertex(e.vertex1);
    if(typeof(this.vertices[e.vertex2])==='undefined')
        this.vertices[e.vertex2]=new Vertex(e.vertex2);
    //add the edge
    if(typeof(this.edges[e.vertex1])==='undefined')
        this.edges[e.vertex1]={};
    this.edges[e.vertex1][e.id]=e;
}
/**
 * Add a vertex to the graph. If a vertex with the same ID already exists then
 * the existing vertex's .data property is replaced with the @param v.data
 */
Graph.prototype.addVertex=function(v){
    if(typeof(this.vertices[v.id])==='undefined')
        this.vertices[v.id]=v;
    else
        this.vertices[v.id].data=v.data;
}

function Vertex(id,data){
    this.id=id;
    this.data=data?data:{};
    //initialize to data.[x|y|z] or generate random number for each
    this.x = this.data.x?this.data.x:-100 + Math.random()*200;
    this.y = this.data.y?this.data.y:-100 + Math.random()*200;
    this.z = this.data.y?this.data.y:-100 + Math.random()*200;
    //set initial velocity to 0
    this.velocity = new Point(0, 0, 0);
    this.mass=this.data.mass?this.data.mass:Math.random();
    this.force=new Point(0,0,0);
}
function Edge(vertex1ID,vertex2ID){
    vertex1ID=vertex1ID?vertex1ID:Math.random()
    vertex2ID=vertex2ID?vertex2ID:Math.random()
    this.id=vertex1ID+"->"+vertex2ID;
    this.vertex1=vertex1ID;
    this.vertex2=vertex2ID;
}
function Point(x, y, z)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}
Point.prototype.plus=function(p){
    this.x +=p.x
    this.y +=p.y
    this.z +=p.z
}
function ForceLayout(o){
    this.repulsion  = o.repulsion?o.repulsion:200;
    this.attraction = o.attraction?o.attraction:0.06;
    this.damping    = o.damping?o.damping:0.9;
    this.graph          = o.graph?o.graph:new Graph();
    this.total_kinetic_energy =0;
    this.animationID=-1;
}
ForceLayout.prototype.draw=function(){
    //vertex velocities initialized to (0,0,0) when a vertex is created
    //vertex positions initialized to random position when created
  cc=0;  do{
        this.total_kinetic_energy =0;
        //for each vertex
        for(var i in this.graph.vertices){
            var thisNode=this.graph.vertices[i];
            // running sum of total force on this particular node
            var netForce=new Point(0,0,0)
            //for each other node
            for(var j in this.graph.vertices){
                if(thisNode!=this.graph.vertices[j]){
                    //net-force := net-force + Coulomb_repulsion( this_node, other_node )
                    netForce.plus(this.CoulombRepulsion( thisNode,this.graph.vertices[j]))
                }
            }
            //for each spring connected to this node
            for(var k in this.graph.edges[thisNode.id]){
                //(this node, node its connected to)
                //pass id of this node and the node its connected to so hookesattraction
                //can update the force on both vertices and return that force to be
                //added to the net force
                this.HookesAttraction(thisNode.id,
                    this.graph.edges[thisNode.id][k].vertex2
                    )
            }
            // without damping, it moves forever
            //         this_node.velocity := (this_node.velocity + timestep * net-force) * damping
            thisNode.velocity.x=(thisNode.velocity.x+thisNode.force.x)*this.damping;
            thisNode.velocity.y=(thisNode.velocity.y+thisNode.force.y)*this.damping;
            thisNode.velocity.z=(thisNode.velocity.z+thisNode.force.z)*this.damping;
            //this_node.position := this_node.position + timestep * this_node.velocity
            thisNode.x=thisNode.velocity.x;
            thisNode.y=thisNode.velocity.y;
            thisNode.z=thisNode.velocity.z;
            //normalize x,y,z???
            //total_kinetic_energy := total_kinetic_energy + this_node.mass * (this_node.velocity)^2
            this.total_kinetic_energy +=thisNode.mass*((thisNode.velocity.x+thisNode.velocity.y+thisNode.velocity.z)*
            (thisNode.velocity.x+thisNode.velocity.y+thisNode.velocity.z))
        }
        cc+=1;
    }while(this.total_kinetic_energy >0.5)
    console.log(cc,this.total_kinetic_energy,this.graph)
    this.cancelAnimation();
}
ForceLayout.prototype.HookesAttraction=function(v1ID,v2ID){
    var a=this.graph.vertices[v1ID]
    var b=this.graph.vertices[v2ID]
    var force=new Point(this.attraction*(b.x - a.x),this.attraction*(b.y - a.y),this.attraction*(b.z - a.z))
    //  hook's attraction
    a.force.x += force.x;
    a.force.y += force.y;
    a.force.z += force.z;
    b.force.x += this.attraction*(a.x - b.x);
    b.force.y += this.attraction*(a.y - b.y);
    b.force.z += this.attraction*(a.z - b.z);
    return force;
}
ForceLayout.prototype.CoulombRepulsion=function(vertex1,vertex2){
    //http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb's_law
    // distance squared = ((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)) + ((y1-y2)*(y1-y2)) + ((z1-z2)*(z1-z2))
    var distanceSquared =
    (
        (vertex1.x-vertex2.x)*(vertex1.x-vertex2.x)+
        (vertex1.y-vertex2.y)*(vertex1.y-vertex2.y)+
        (vertex1.z-vertex2.z)*(vertex1.z-vertex2.z)
        );
    if(distanceSquared==0) distanceSquared = 0.001;
    var coul = this.repulsion / distanceSquared;
    return new Point(coul * (vertex1.x-vertex2.x),coul * (vertex1.y-vertex2.y), coul * (vertex1.z-vertex2.z));
}
ForceLayout.prototype.animate=function(){
    if(this.animating)
        this.animationID=requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
    this.draw();
}
ForceLayout.prototype.cancelAnimation=function(){
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.animationID);
    this.animating=false;
}
ForceLayout.prototype.redraw=function(){
    this.animating=true;
    this.animate();
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var g= new Graph();
    for(var i=0;i<=100;i++){
        var v1=new Vertex(Math.random(), {})
        var v2=new Vertex(Math.random(), {})
        var e1= new Edge(v1.id,v2.id);
        g.addEdge(e1);
    }
    console.log(g);
    var l=new ForceLayout({
        graph:g
    });
    l.redraw();
});
```

Comment: *"My first attempt didn't work"* - **How** did it not work?

Comment: Conceptual issues may include not increasing the damping/friction over time to dissipate the energy inherent in the starting position of the system. Implementation issues may include anything, depending on how your attempt "didn't work".

Comment: @ninjagecko It didn't work in the sense that, I can never seem to generate reasonable positions for each vertex. They're usually 0.x for x,y and z

Comment: I assume you mean that usually all coordinates of your vertices are 0<=value<=1. This doesn't really mean anything taken out of context (perhaps you are working with a canvas that mostly the unit cube, and this is good). I would highly recommend showing example output of your implementation (see http://jsfiddle.net ), and linking to what you would like, e.g. http://dhotson.github.com/springy/demo.html

Comment: I think there are a few things I'm not getting, I don't know what they are but there seems to be a disconnect. I haven't been drawing, just printing the x,y position of each vertex as in http://jsfiddle.net/xk7Kz/2/ What I'd like is to produce points like what is used to create the demo on this page http://blog.ivank.net/force-based-graph-drawing-in-javascript.html The springy demo is ok but the one in this link feels nicer somehow.

Comment: 1) You cannot properly debug this without drawing it. You need to write a routine to draw it. Because I've seen it before, I could sort of get an idea by picking a random point and tracking it. Printing out the final position of everything like you were doing gives you no useful debugging insight. 2) The attraction seems to be working, roughly. You should expect the distances to be roughly your natural spring distance (if your spring distance is 1, this is a normal result). 3) When I looked up the spring distance, you seem to be implementing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke's_law incorrectly

Comment: ... namely, you current have the spring between two points pulling on it if the points are apart. What a spring actually does is it has two parameters, a natural length and a spring constant `k`. If a spring is stretched, it will pull inwards with a force of `(length-naturalLength)*springConstant`. If a spring is compresssed, it will push outwards with a force of `-(length-naturalLength)*springConstant`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least one reason this isn't working is that you are implementing the springs incorrectly. ([Hooke's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law))

Namely, you current have the spring between two points tugging them together all the time. What a spring actually does is it has two parameters, a natural length and a spring constant `k`. If a spring is stretched, it will pull inwards with a force of `(length-naturalLength)*springConstant`. If a spring is compresssed, it will push outwards with a force of `-(length-naturalLength)*springConstant`.

Printing out the final positions of everything gives you very little debug information. I would highly recommend that if you still have trouble, that you write your display code (which you'll have to do anyway) now so you can visualize what's going on. Alternatively you should track the motion of only 2 particles with a spring between them, outputting debug information at every timestep. You should restrict what you print out to only one vector of interest.

Additionally if you are further running into trouble, you can decrease your timestep.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up writing the drawing code earlier and spotted a few things. Your explanation about the spring actually fits in with one bug I noticed. Thanks, I'm still playing around with it.